# Selecting the top N rows of a dataframe based on a threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this data set with keys and their associated confidence values.

```
values = [('S08', -6276.0), ('S01', -6360.0), ('S03', -6504.0), ('C01', -521682.0), 
          ('C03', -556262.0), ('C08', -558108.0), ('S06', -1723974.0),
          ('S09', -2379806.0), ('C06', -2472398.0), ('C09', -2930688.0)]
df = pd.DataFrame(values, columns=['key', 'confidence'])

   key  confidence
0  S08     -6276.0
1  S01     -6360.0
2  S03     -6504.0
3  C01   -521682.0
4  C03   -556262.0
5  C08   -558108.0
6  S06  -1723974.0
7  S09  -2379806.0
8  C06  -2472398.0
9  C09  -2930688.0
```

**In this case**, top 3 rows are the ones with very high confidence values and need to be selected. The rest of the rows (starting from the fourth one) have confidence values are very far away from top 3 and need to be discarded. TopN rows could vary from 1 to 9 dynamically.

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: is the lengh of df always 10?

Comment: Use k-means or kernel density estimation to get more accurate results.

Comment: @mwweb I looked at k-means and it makes sense. On the other hand, using MeanShift seems a more suitable solution for this problem.

Comment: Still you have to chose the bandwidth. A large value might result in merging distinct clusters.  A very small might result in too many clusters. If the lengh of your array is larger than 10 , lets say 20 or 30 , i would use silhouette coefficient clustering for finding an optimal K and use the K in K means.

Comment: "estimate_bandwidth" method works ok so far to establish a proper bandwidth. I'll take a look at SC clustering...

Comment: I work in the past with SC for chosing k and kmeans and for my dataset the results were good but not great. It all depend on how your data is structured. If its always like the example here the threshold method is ok.

Answer (score 3):

Apply a threshold for filtering with *boolean indexing*.

```
thresh = 0.0005 * df.confidence.std() # for example 
df = df[df.confidence.diff().fillna(0).abs() < thresh]
df
   key  confidence
0  S08     -6276.0
1  S01     -6360.0
2  S03     -6504.0
```

---

To retain `NaNs`, use *`df.where`*

```
df.confidence = df.confidence.where(df.confidence.diff().fillna(0).abs() < thresh)
df  
   key  confidence
0  S08     -6276.0
1  S01     -6360.0
2  S03     -6504.0
3  C01         NaN
4  C03         NaN
5  C08         NaN
6  S06         NaN
7  S09         NaN
8  C06         NaN
9  C09         NaN
```

Comment: TopN rows are dynamic. Could be 1 or could be 4 or 5. i.e If you put nlargest(4), you get the fourth one as well which is not desired.

Comment: @mevdiven I understood. Look at my answer now.

Comment: @COLDSPEED very close. I've added std deviation of the data set to make it dynamic


thresh = 0.0005 * df.confidence.std()

Answer (score 2):

Or using `pandas.DataFrame.nlargest`

```
df=pandas.DataFrame(values, columns=['key', 'confidence']).nlargest(3, 'confidence')
```

### nlargest(3, 'confidence')

```
   key  confidence
0  S08     -6276.0
1  S01     -6360.0
2  S03     -6504.0
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.17.0/generated/pandas.DataFrame.nlargest.html

Comment: Based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46186671/select-the-topn-rows-and-reject-bottom-outliers-based-on-confidence-values/46186723#comment79336327_46186723, this is not what OP wants.